# jquery: when click multiple elements then toggle new class

Tags: javascript, jquery

please help with the following problem, i want to create a script that once you had clicked all the skyblue squares, the red square change the class showing green color. Many thanks in advance!!!

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37gpC.jpg)

language: lang-js

```
var mouse = function(){
  $('.bt').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('bt2');
  });
}

var snd = function(){ 
  if ($('#1, #2, #3, #4, #5').hasClass('bt2')){
     $('.bt3').toggleClass('live');
  }

}

$(document).ready(mouse);
$(document).ready(snd);
```

language: lang-css

```
.bt {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:deepskyblue;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:25px;
}

.bt2 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:orange;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:25px;
}

.bt3 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:25px;
}
.live {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:green;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:25px;
}

body {
  background-color:#121212;
}
```

language: lang-html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="1" class="bt"></div>
  <div id="2" class="bt"></div>
  <div id="3" class="bt"></div>
  <div id="4" class="bt"></div>
  <div id="5" class="bt"></div>
  <div id="6" class="bt3"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a specific problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var mouse = function(){
  $('.bt').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('bt2');
  snd();
  });
}

var snd = function(){ 
  if ($('#1, #2, #3, #4, #5').filter('.bt2').length === $('#1, #2, #3, #4, #5').length ){
     $('.bt3').toggleClass('live');
  }else{
     $('.bt3').removeClass('live');
  }

}

$(document).ready(mouse);
$(document).ready(snd);
```

```css
.bt {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:deepskyblue;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:25px;
}

.bt2 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:orange;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:25px;
}

.bt3 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:25px;
}
.live {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:green;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:25px;
}

body {
  background-color:#121212;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="1" class="bt"></div>
  <div id="2" class="bt"></div>
  <div id="3" class="bt"></div>
  <div id="4" class="bt"></div>
  <div id="5" class="bt"></div>
  <div id="6" class="bt3"></div>

</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

1. Added `snd()` to the click event listener so the check is executed after every click.
2. In the `if` you have a comparation whether the total number of elements with class `bt2` equals the number of the elements per se (the 5 buttons).
3. Added an `else` in case the user changes one button back to blue (not sure if you need, but here you go).

Comment: Don't know why someone downvoted you so I balanced. I didn't know this way to proceed, thanks !

Comment: Thanks for the details, and yes i needed restore the previous class. works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I shortened your version a bit and added the toggling of the `live` class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($('#1, #2, #3, #4, #5').hasClass('bt2')) {
    $('.bt3').toggleClass('live');
  }

  $('.bt').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('bt2');
     $('.bt3').toggleClass('live', $('.bt:not(.bt2)').length ? false : true );
  });
});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/yf19psqr/)

The function [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state) accepts a second parameter (boolean) which determins wether to remove or add the specified class(es).
In this case the state is set via a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), which checks if there are any elements with the class `bt` that are [not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) having the class `bt2`

Is there any specific reason you are assigning the function to variables and use them for the '.ready()' handler?

Answer (score 0):

One can just check whether there're any elements with the `.bt` class left with the `!$('.bt').length` expression - it checks whether collection of elements with class `bt` has any members. If there're no elements in the collection just toggle the element which we need to make green. I don't know why `snd` function was introduced at all. I would remove it.

```
var mouse = function(){
    $('.bt').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('bt2');
        if (!$('.bt').length) {
            $('#6').toggleClass('live');
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Maybe you could add some words explaining why this would solve the issue

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @FrankerZ, explanation has been added. Hope this is ok now.